# XML deserialization with an optional list

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I am trying to find out how to handle the de-serialization of XML. I do understand how to use the built in serialization and have done so before.

My issue this time is that one section on the XML may be a list of messages or a single message.

EDIT: The XML fragments below are snippets from a well formed XML document. When received, the XML will contain either the message list or a single message. The containing XML was left out for clarity and brevity.

The XML fragment will look either like this...

```
<messageList>
    <message>message1</message>
    <message>message2</message>
</messageList>
```

or like this...

```
<message>singleMessage</message>
```

Is it possible to handle this using the built in .Net de-serialization or will I need to hand code this?

Comment: In the schema, the two above cases are completely separate entities, because they represent different schemas. Would that work for what you need?

Comment: Why wouldn't there be a root node in both cases?

Comment: The XML listed are fragments that will be contained in a larger, well formed XML document. In either case an XML document will be received containing either a '<message>' or a '<messageList>' node.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[XmlRoot("MessageRoot", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class MessageRoot
{

    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true, ElementName = "message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("messageList")]
    [XmlArrayItem("message")]
    public string[] Messages { get; set; }
}



   <MessageRoot>   
     <message> message </message>  
     <messageList>
       <message>message1</message>
       <message>message2</message>   
      </messageList>  
   </MessageRoot>
```